# Check if strings are JSON format

Tags: json, go

How to check if a given string is in form of multiple json string separated by spaces/newline?

For example,
given: `"test" 123 {"Name": "mike"}` (3 json concatenated with space)
return: `true`, since each of item (`"test"` `123` and `{"Name": "mike"}`) is a valid json.

In Go, I can write a O(N^2) function like:

```
// check given string is json or multiple json concatenated with space/newline
func validateJSON(str string) error {
    // only one json string
    if isJSON(str) {
        return nil
    }
    // multiple json string concatenate with spaces
    str = strings.TrimSpace(str)
    arr := []rune(str)
    start := 0
    end := 0
    for start < len(str) {
        for end < len(str) && !unicode.IsSpace(arr[end]) {
            end++
        }
        substr := str[start:end]
        if isJSON(substr) {
            for end < len(str) && unicode.IsSpace(arr[end]) {
                end++
            }
            start = end
        } else {
            if end == len(str) {
                return errors.New("error when parsing input: " + substr)
            }
            for end < len(str) && unicode.IsSpace(arr[end]) {
                end++
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func isJSON(str string) bool {
    var js json.RawMessage
    return json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &js) == nil
}
```

But this won't work for large input.

Comment: So the whole thing would be valid JSON if the top-level spaces (outside quoted strings) were replaced by commas and the whole thing surrounded by square brackets?

Comment: I don't know if this is an academic or personal exercise but a [Valid](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Valid) function exists already.

Comment: Yes @TedHopp. I also wish the input json strings are separated by comma >.<, then it won't be such a hard problem to me..

Comment: Thanks @squiguy, Vaild won't help, because input is not json, but multiple json concatenated with spaces/newlines.

Comment: It seems like there's a big issue with your premise: `"test" 123` is not valid JSON. Given that, you can ignore anything that doesn't start with a `{` and go to a matching `}`

Comment: Hi @Verran, I know `"test" 123` is not valid JSON, but I treat it as my valid input because it is **in form of multiple json string separated by spaces/newline**

Comment: Have you tried encoding/json.Decoder on your stream repeatedly? Becuase I think the whole purpose of Decoder is to work its way through such streams of JSON elements.

Comment: @vancexu: If you are accepting both "valid JSON" and "not valid JSON" then you're going to have to be _much_ clearer about your requirements before we can come up with a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options.  The simplest, from a coding standpoint, is going to be just to decode the JSON string normally. You can make this most efficient by decoding to an empty struct:

```
package main

import "encoding/json"

func main() {
    input := []byte(`{"a":"b", "c": 123}`)
    var x struct{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(input, &x); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    input = []byte(`{"a":"b", "c": 123}xxx`) // This one fails
    if err := json.Unmarshal(input, &x); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

([playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/VheJf-cd-yD))

This method has a few potential drawbacks:

- It only works with a single JSON object. That is, a list of objects (as requested in the question) will fail, without additional logic.
- As pointed out by @icza in comments, it only works with JSON objects, so bare arrays, numbers, or strings will fail. To accomodate these types, `interface{}` must be used, which introduces the potential for some serious performance penalties.
- The throw-away `x` value must still be allocated, and at least one reflection call is likely under the sheets, which may introduce a noticeable performance penalty for some workloads.

Given these limitations, my recommendation is to use the second option: loop through the entire JSON input, ignoring the actual contents. This is made simple with the standard library [json.Decoder](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "io"
)

func main() {
        input := []byte(`{"a":"b", "c": 123}`)
        dec := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(input))
        for {
            _, err := dec.Token()
            if err == io.EOF {
                break // End of input, valid JSON
            }
            if err != nil {
                panic(err) // Invalid input
            }
        }

        input = []byte(`{"a":"b", "c": 123}xxx`) // This input fails
        dec = json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(input))
        for {
            _, err := dec.Token()
            if err == io.EOF {
                break // End of input, valid JSON
            }
            if err != nil {
                panic(err) // Invalid input
            }
        }
}
```

([playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/QHYK3aCEImk))

Comment: The first option has some drawbacks, e.g. it can only unmarshal JSON objects (and fails to unmarshal valid values like `123` or `"abc"` or JSON objects), so to make it work, `interface{}` is needed to handle all cases. The second option does not have that restriction, good idea with getting only the tokens.

Comment: @icza: Good observation.

Comment: Thanks @Flimzy, option 2 using Token helped me solve my problem gracefully. I tested it against 150KB input string, blazing fast less than sec.

Answer (score 0):

As Volker mentioned in the comments, use a *json.Decoder to decode all json documents in your input successively:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    input := `"test" 123 {"Name": "mike"}`
    dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(input))

    for {
            var x json.RawMessage
            switch err := dec.Decode(&x); err {
            case nil:
                    // not done yet
            case io.EOF:
                    return // success
            default:
                    log.Fatal(err)
            }
    }
}
```

Try it on the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/1OKOii9mRHn

Comment: It will be more efficient to decode to a `struct{}`--this will still validate the JSON input, but won't allocate any memory.

Comment: @Flimzy, but fail if the JSON document isn't an object. However, json.RawMessage is probably still much better than interface{}. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Indeed, json.RawMessage is a good compromise between functionality of struct{} and performance of interface{}. Although ideal would still be not to allocate any memory at all. A custom type with a no-op Unmarshal method could accomplish this. But probably iterating through the tokens is even better.

Answer (score 0):

Try [fastjson.Scanner](https://godoc.org/github.com/valyala/fastjson#Scanner):

```
s := `"test" 123 {"Name": "mike"}`

var sc fastjson.Scanner
sc.Init(s)

// Iterate over a stream of json objects
for sc.Next() {}
if sc.Error() != nil {
    fmt.Println("ok")
} else {
    fmt.Println("false")
}
```