# How to validate JSON when using unmarshal into generic interface?

Tags: arrays, json, go

I want to validate byte array data if it contains valid JSON using unmarsall method into interface.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func isJSON(s string) bool {
    var js map[string]interface{}

    return json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &js) == nil
}

func main() {
    var tests = []string{
        `{"a":"b"}`,
        `[{"a":"b"},{"a":"b"}]`,
    }

    for _, t := range tests {
        fmt.Printf("isJSON(%s) = %v\n\n", t, isJSON(t))
    }

}
```

Both input test parameters are valid JSON strings, but it validate based on the interface 'map[string]interface{}'

```
{
    "a": "b"
}

[{
    "a": "b"
}, {
    "a": "b"
}]
```

I want to validate the JSON text. JSON text is a serialized object or array. Hence looking for a solution which support all valid cases for JSON text as I added test cases in [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ajrHWEVr-7x).

How can I make this interface i.e var `map[string]interface{}` generic so it support both test cases of valid JSON string?

[Solved: Playground Link](https://play.golang.org/p/ajrHWEVr-7x)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if strings are JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777882/check-if-strings-are-json-format)

Comment: @Peter The suggested answer cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type struct {}. Hence does no meet the requirement.

Comment: I was referring to the json.Decoder.Token() and json.RawMessage options.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for pointing it out. I tried your answer using `json.Decoder.Token()` and `json.RawMessage`, it is not validating JSON as an object. the "sfdsf" is a valid JSON string but not JSON object. Here is play link https://play.golang.org/p/_EMloRrLg8D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `map[string]interface{}` but simply `interface{}`. The second example is of type `[]interface{}` and there are more types of valid json.

Here your working code. I added a few more cases of valid json.

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rXH2DPq3_lw)

Here the code if you want to allow only maps and slices:

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NP6EI7h4Jm1)

Comment: In your added case, the `"sfdsf"` is a valid `JSON` string value but not the JSON object. A JSON text is serialized object or array. Therefore it would not be legal to use this to validate a JSON with an internet media type `application/json`.

Comment: I could argue with you here but I will just edit my answer.

Comment: See [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777882/check-if-strings-are-json-format/48781823) for more efficient alternatives to decoding to interface{}.

Comment: @TehSphinX That works! I added more cases and simplify the `if` conditions https://play.golang.org/p/ajrHWEVr-7x

Comment: @Peter The suggested answer cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type struct {}

Comment: @Peter Thanks for pointing it out. I tried your answer using `json.Decoder.Token()` and `json.RawMessage`, it is not validating JSON as an object. the "sfdsf" is a valid JSON string but not JSON object. Here is play link https://play.golang.org/p/_EMloRrLg8D